# how to change the character spacing in a field of fillable pdf form using javascript

Tags: javascript, pdf, adobe, acrobat, fillable

I am modifying a pdf as fillable. I have changed the spacing between the letters in the fields. as one number into a single cell. How to do this with JavaScript?
[image]

The following code didn't work either

```
var field = this.getField("field1");
var textField = field.getArray()[0];
textField.textFont.textState.charSpacing = 1.5;
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use comb fields, and you set the distance between characters via the field length and the `charLimit` property.

You also could set the `richText` property for the field. However, programmatically dealing with richtext fields is a bit messy. Therefore, comb fields are preferred in such a situation.